# Rails - Incrementally build join record for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, dynamic, model-associations, join

This was the original question I asked but think below adds a bit more detail to the scenario: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124485/rails-link-to-tag-to-build-join-record-in-rails)

I'd like to have a form that allows me to incrementally add association records to an object - that also has to be created upon form submission.

Model setup (-< is one to many)

Customer -< CustomerOrder -< OrderLineItem -< Product

In my controller I have a custom route that is:

```
  def custom_order
    puts "custom_order called"
    @cakeTypes = CakeType.all
    @cakes = Cake.all
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.customer_orders.build
  end
```

A customer can only submit one order at a time so that is why I build the customer_orders object. I could include a builder on order_line_items but this is dynamic and what my question is about.

I have a link_to in my form below that has add_to_order - this calls a bit of javascript which sends an ajax request to the controller to grab the relevant details for the order after user selects from a dropdown the product, quantity etc they want.

Am I going in the right direction of "Incrementally Building" (as I describe it) my join records for a nested form for objects that I'd like to have all created at once? How should one do this via the "Rails way"?

My form: html comments added to further describe what I'm trying to do:

```
<%= form_with(model: customer, local: true, url: "/custom_order") do |form| %>

  <!-- customer form fields, name, phone, email-->
  <%= render 'customer_fields', f: form %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :customer_orders do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :date_needed %>
      <%= builder.date_select :date_needed %>
      <br />
      <%= builder.label :comments %>
      <%= builder.text_area :comments %>

    <% end %>
  </div>

  <!-- order form -->
  <div class="field">

    <!-- We want to display to user the cake sizes available depending on the cake they select -->
    <!-- the cake and size they select should inform the cake_price_id which is a hidden field -->
    <!-- {'data-order-line-item-cake' => "#{line_item_builder.options[:child_index]}"} -->
    <%= collection_select :order_line_item, :cake_id, Cake.order(:name), :id, :name %>
    <%= grouped_collection_select :order_line_item, :cake_size_id, Cake.all, :cake_sizes, :name, :id, :name %>
    <%= label_tag :quantity %>
    <%= text_field_tag :quantity %>
    <%= link_to "Add to order", {}, id: 'add_to_order', remote: true %> <!-- , method: :post, remote: true  %> -->

    <!-- A "customer" on this page will only every create one order -->
    <!-- so each item should field should have -->
    <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][date_needed] -->
    <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][comments] -->
    <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][total] HIDDEN!-->

    <div id="order-items">
        <% if false %>
          <%= text_field_tag "customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][1][customer_order_id]", "", disabled: true%>
        <% end %>
        <!-- <input type="text" name="customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][1][customer_order_id]" id="customer_customer_orders_attributes_0_order_line_items_attributes_1_customer_order_id" value="" disabled="disabled"> -->
        <!-- names -->
        <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][0..N][customer_order_id] -->
        <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][0..N][cake_price_id] -->
        <!--customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][0..N][quantity] -->
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Order" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My coffeescript - It's a bit hacky at the moment as I'm still learning and also trying things out. I would like to know if what I'm doing so far is correct and if possible how do I go about building the join records dynamically?

```
$ ->
  $('#add_to_order').click ->
    console.log("add to order!")
    myData =
      cake_id: $('#order_line_item_cake_id :selected').val()
      cake_size_id: $('#order_line_item_cake_size_id :selected').val()
      quantity: $('#quantity').val()
    $.ajax
      url: "/build_order_item"
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'json'
      data: (myData)
      success: (data) ->
        console.log(data)
        #$('#order-items').append("<h6>#{data.quantity} - #{data.size} of #{data.cake} - #{data.price}</h6>")
        $('#order-items').append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"jims_cake_price_id\" id=\"jims_cake_price_id\" value=#{data.cake_price_id}><br />")
      error: ->
        alert "Something went wrong"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution - however I'm still not sure if this is the "Rails Way"

I've had to rely on the dependencies / limitations my app has so far

Namely: 
1) a customer can only make one order at a time (there is also no login/authentication to associate users)

Knowing this and from understanding how rails builds id's and names via associations I'm now dynamically constructing the html required to generate the join table elements.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer[customer_orders_attributes][0][order_line_items_attributes][0][cake_price_id]" value="1">
```

(Note the first '0' is hardcoded because I know this will be the first order)

The second '0' is generated via javascript. This is the index I re-order on when an element is removed.

i.e.

if customer adds 3 products then the index's will be 0,1,2 - if they remove index 0, then the id's will have to be updated to reflect 0 and 1.

Issues faced with above solution:
I have to reorder the id of elements when one is removed - not so bad because they will always be 0..N-1 for the number of items ordered.

What I'd really really like to know is if I'm going "off the Rails" so to speak... Is what I'm doing above correct? Or is this perfectly acceptable? Or am I being just to worried about doing it the "Rails way" and just go with it - if it works for me?

Any response much appreciated.